# NSButton title not centered vertically but a little lower

Tags: swift, macos, nsbutton

I'm new to macOS programming and this may be a silly question but it got me stuck.

I'm trying to subclass the `NSButton` and create a more customizable button class. Everything worked fine except the title which is not centered **vertically**, offset several pixels down from the vertical center to be more specific.

Then I found out that even the native `NSButton`'s title also has this "problem". Here's the example:

[click me to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ideKB.png)

For comparison I put a normal **square** `NSButton` on the left, and the right one is my customized `NSButton`, and the titles in both buttons placed a little lower than the center.

So here's my questions:

1. **Why does this happen?**
2. **How to set absolutely centered title?**

---

Here's my code for setting the customizable title (in case you want to know):

I'm setting the `attributedTtile` using a library called [SwiftyAttributes](https://github.com/eddiekaiger/SwiftyAttributes), that's why those `.withFont` stuff appear.

```
let paragraph = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraph.alignment = .center

attributedTitle = title
  .withFont(.systemFont(ofSize: 13))
  .withParagraphStyle(paragraph)
  .withTextColor(titleColor)
```

Answer (score 2):

this answer help me and maybe answer **Why does this happen**:

[Link](https://www.mac-help.com/threads/nsbuttoncell-wrong-title-alignement.104517/)

Well, I tested here using the code quoted in the link and got this code:

```
override func titleRect(forBounds rect: NSRect) -> NSRect {
    var theRect = super.titleRect(forBounds: rect)
    theRect.origin.y = rect.origin.y+rect.size.height-(theRect.size.height+(theRect.origin.y-rect.origin.y))-2;
    return theRect
}
```

Overriding the **NSButtonCell** ***func titleRect(forBounds rect: NSRect) -> NSRect*** I was able to centralize the text.

Comment: Link no longer works and as the original question is about NSButton and not NSButtonCell, it's worth mentioning that NSButton does not have titleRect function that could be overriden.